# web scraping in pythonanywhere not working

Tags: python, web-services, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pythonanywhere

I need help with a little web scraper I have written and put into my pythonanywhere account to let it run several times per day.

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import random

list_all_results = []


for i in range(1, 3):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 2))

    print("Scraping page " + str(i) + "/745")

    try:
        URL = "https://www.futbin.com/players?page=" + str(i)
        platform = "pc"
        cookies = {"platform": platform}
        page = requests.get(URL, cookies=cookies)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

        result_names = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "player_name_players_table"})
        result_ratings = soup.find_all(
            "span",
            attrs={"class": lambda r: r.startswith("form rating ut21") if r else False},
        )
        result_rarity = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "mobile-hide-table-col"})

        result_prices_pc = soup.find_all(
            "span", attrs={"class": "pc_color font-weight-bold"}
        )

        list_names = []
        list_ratings = []
        list_rarities = []
        list_prices = []

        for name in result_names:
            list_names.append(name.text)

        for rating in result_ratings:
            list_ratings.append(rating.text)

        for rarity in result_rarity:
            list_rarities.append(rarity.text)

        for price in result_prices_pc:
            n = price.text.strip()
            if "K" in n:
                n2 = n.replace("K", "")
                full_int = int(float(n2) * 1000)
                list_prices.append(full_int)
            elif "M" in n:
                n2 = n.replace("M", "")
                full_int = int(float(n2) * 1000000)
                list_prices.append(full_int)
            else:
                list_prices.append(int(price.text.strip()))

        int_list_length = len(list_names)
        for i in range(0, int_list_length):
            list_all_results.append(
                tuple(
                    (list_names[i], list_ratings[i], list_rarities[i], list_prices[i])
                )
            )

        with open("/home/exec85/scrape/pc.txt", "a") as f:  # create new .txt file and write content to file
            f.write(f"{list_all_results}")



    except:
        pass

print("FINISHED")
```

For some reason I dont get any result printed, so I assume nothing gets scraped and also the .txt file is not created.
Even if I manually create the .txt file it gets not filled.

Running the script on my local machine all works fine.

Comment: When you remove the `try...except` and run it on the server, do you get any error?

Comment: if you want to know what happens why don't you log the exception instead of muting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well but if you want the code works on PythonAnywhere, you need to have [a paid account](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/) but you can reach [this site list](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).